# Encountered System.StackOverflowException in .NET3.5&AnyCpu when return a struct

Tags: c#, struct, stack-overflow

I have a .net windows forms application target both .Net framework 3.5 and 4 , and target to any cpu, when I start the app with Debug(F5) in visual studio target .net 3.5, I encountered StackOverflowException, but I can start app without debug(ctrl+F5) successfully. Also I can start app with **debug**(ctrl+F5) target .net4 successfully. Can anyone tell me the possible reason. Thanks. code as below:

```
public struct AStuctType : IInterface {
    // some properties 

    // if changed the return type to IInterface, will not encounter StackOverflowException in debug/.net 3.5
    // but will encounter StackOverflowException when convert the value to AStuctType
    public static AStuctType LoadFromXml(XmlReader reader) {
        var result = new AStuctType();
        //...read xml and assign result properties' values.

        // exception encountered here
        return result.
    }
}
```

Comment: An SOE is rarely generated at the exact spot where the bug is located.  Look in the caller of this code.

Comment: if AStuctType  is struct, it's declared using the keyword "struct". Modify declaration struct AStuctType : IInterface.

Comment: sorry, missed struct keyword in the question.

Comment: Could you show us part of the stacktrace? There's probably a repeated cycle of invocations within it causing the issue.

Comment: @SimonSvensson Actually, I would be curious to __ever__ see a stackoverflow exception without repititon... I could imagine it in rare cases with large arrays allocated on the stack, but otherwise it would need a hell lot of chained functions :)

Comment: the caller of the method LoadFromXml, will add the result of LoadFromXml to a Dictionary<string, IInterface>, I also defined other stucts derived from IInterface, only this one have this issue.